# Error 6: curl can't resolve host name

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm running PHP 5.6.36 running on windows server 12R2 under IIS 8.5
Whenever I call this code I get an "error code: 6" echoed and an empty $responseText, although I'm able to reach this address with the browser.

I've tried toggling the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to true settings and using https:// addresses, but to no avail. Don't get why I can reach these addresses through the browser, but not from the command line.

```
function genericGet($url,$userName,$passWord){

//overriding $url for the purposes of test
$url = "http://www.google.com";

$reqDefaults = array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST            => false,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH        => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERNAME        => $userName,
    CURLOPT_PASSWORD        => $passWord
);

$curlReq = curl_init();
$responseText = curl_exec($curlReq);
echo "error code:".curl_errno($curlReq)."\r\n";
curl_close($curlReq);

return $responseText;
}
```

Comment: PHP 5.3 has been [EOL for ages](https://secure.php.net/eol.php), please consider upgrading tot at least 5.6 and preferably 7.2 for good support and security fixes.

Comment: Sorry meant 5.**6**.36 edited just now to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally worked this out. There was an application proxy running on the server. I checked the internet settings in Firefox and found the proxy address then added the CURLOPT_PROXY setting to my setopt array and it worked. Final code looked like this:

```
function genericGet($url,$userName,$passWord){

//overriding $url for the purposes of test
$url = "http://www.google.com";

$reqDefaults = array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST            => false,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH        => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERNAME        => $userName,
    CURLOPT_PASSWORD        => $passWord,
    CURLOPT_PROXY           => 'proxyaddress:8080'
);

$curlReq = curl_init();
$responseText = curl_exec($curlReq);
echo "error code:".curl_errno($curlReq)."\r\n";
curl_close($curlReq);

return $responseText;
}
```